# How can I export dependency function and use a specific function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to export function `c` and use it in app.js but I think It would occur dependency error because If I import `c` and use it, func `c` calls `a, b` but file can't find func a and b. how can I implement this? Here's a example code what I was trying to do.

```
function a(){}
function b(){}
function c(){ a(); b();}
export default c
```

Comment: There would be no issues calling `c` after importing it.

Comment: *"file can't find func a and b"* That's not how JavaScript works. `c` is defined in the scope where `a` and `b` are defined, hence it has access to them. Your example would work.